# How remember that a React hooks component is unmounted, so can avoid state changes?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

With old class based React.js code, I can do like this, to remember that a component has been unmounted:

```
  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    this.isGone = true;
  },

  loadUsers: function() {
    Server.loadUsers(..., (response) => {
      if (this.isGone) return;
      ...
    });
  }
```

**How can one do the same thing, with hooks based components?**

Here's a sample hooks function component, where I'm unsure about how to remember that it's been unmounted, so I can `return` before calling any `setSomeState`:

```
export const GroupMembers = React.createFactory(function(props) {

  const [membersOrNull, setMembers] = React.useState(null);
  let isGone = false;  // ? (se [222] below

  React.useEffect(() => {
    Server.listGroupMembers(someGroupId, (response) => {
     if (/* is unmounted ?? */) return;
     setMembers(response.members);
    });
    return () => { /* how remember is unmounted?
                      would isGone = true; work? */ };
  }, []);

  ...

  return ..., Button({ title: "Remove all members", onClick: () => {
    Server.removeAllMembers(someGroupId, () => {
     if (/* is unmounted ?? */) return;
     setMembers([]);
    });
  }});
```

I suppose I cannot use `const [isGone, setGone] = useState(false)` because I shouldn't try to access the state (read `isGone`) after has been unmounted. And if I *[222]* add a local `let isGone = false` inside the function, it seems to me that various callbacks created inside the function, will refer to different "instances" of this local variable, depending on in which different `GroupMembers(..)` invokation the different callbacks were created? or am I mistaken and this works? — Maybe I could create an outer wrapper function with a local `let isGone = false`, however, this adds another wrapping function and indentation :- /

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using the `isGone` flag outside of the `useEffect` method too, you can make use of `useRef` to store variables like

```
export const GroupMembers = React.createFactory(function(props) {

  const [membersOrNull, setMembers] = React.useState(null);
  const isGone = useRef(false);  // ? (se [222] below

  React.useEffect(() => {
    Server.listGroupMembers(someGroupId, (response) => {
     if (isGone.current) return;
     setMembers(response.members);
    });
    return () => { 
       isGone.current = true;
    };
  }, []);

  ...

  return ..., Button({ title: "Remove all members", onClick: () => {
    Server.removeAllMembers(someGroupId, () => {
     if (isGone.current) return;
     setMembers([]);
    });
  }});
```

> PS: A better way to handle such things is to cancel the request when
>   you are leaving the page instead of waiting for the response only to
>   neglect it.

Comment: Hmm to me this seems to go against the React.js docs: *The returned object [from useRef] will persist for the full lifetime of the component* (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)  — however, this: `Server.removeAllMembers(... () => { if (isGone.current) ...`  might access `isGone` (i.e. the "returned object") *after* the component has been destroyed (a bit later when the server has replied), and what then happens, isn't mentioned in the docs (undefined behavior?).

Comment: Once the response is received, the variable is of no use and will get garbage collected since no other node will keep reference to this

Comment: Still, maybe not impossible that, in the future, the React developers decide that it's an error to access `someRef.current` after the component has been destroyed? (It's not mentioned in the docs if that's supposed to work or not.) Could they for example replace `.current` with a getter that logs & throws an error? — So, although this code works today (I suppose it does?), maybe it's a bit less future compatible, than just doing away with the ref, and using a plain variable instead. If you want to, have a look at @skyboyer's other answer here.

Comment: Any particular reason you're using a ref b.t.w.? I think a plain `let isGone;` and `isGone = true` would work equally well ( + less code) ?  — B.t.w. yes I agree that cancelling the request would be better :- )

Comment: The reason that I uses useRef is because you were using the same variable in two places and there wasn't a common closure than the functional component where if you declare variables they will be reset to default value on every render and we don't want to fall in a situtation where the isGone value is overwritten by some unexpected re-render

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation. I could reproduce the behaviour you described: I added an unexpected re-render (via *setTimeut* + a dummy *setState*). And yes this made the arrow functions "capture" the `isGone` in the wrong closures (that is, after the dummy extra re-render), so they never noticed `isGone` being set to true (in the original closure). The arrow functions thereafter proceeded with trying to update the state, after the component had been unmounted. React logged an error  about that.

Comment: Then I modified the code to use `useRef` instead, and thereater everything worked fine. Ok so this is the generic & safe answer then, and the other, relying on a local `let isGone = false` works in certain cases only.

Answer (score 2):

just use local variable accessed through closure

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  let isActual = true;
  Server.listGroupMembers(someGroupId, (response) => {
     if (!isActual) return;
     setMembers(response.members);
  });
  return () => {isActual = false;};
}, []);
```

in this case flag would be updated on unmounting only. but in general case(with some unempty dependencies for `useEffect`) it will use as well. So in case of sequential renderings you could be sure you never process older request.

PS most universal way is cancelling request when it's possible.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This works in the code snippet above, however, in the code snippet in the question itself, there's another code block, with a `Button({ ... onClick: () => if (isGone) ....` and if there's an "unexpected" re-render, then this button onClick handler, will thereafter reference `isGone` from the wrong closure, and won't notice `isGone` changing to true in the original closure. So I'd say, when using this approach, one needs to carefully think about what'll happen if there's an "unexpected" re-render of the component. (There's another answer that uses `useRef` instead.)